# framework not found WatchKit

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, devops

I am trying to build a very basic app on devops and i keep getting

```
error MT5209 : Native linking error : framework not found WatchKit [/Users/runner/runners/2.166.2/work/1/s/WeatherApp.iOS/WeatherApp.iOS.csproj]
```

anyone ever seen this before ?

[image]

Comment: Hi , could you share a screenshot of solution view ? If it's a sample project , you also can share the link here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out I changed the version of the agent specification from macOS-10.14 to macOS-10.15 and it cleared things up.

[image]